# Open an URL in a web browser that isn't safari, with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, safari, jailbreak

I'm making a simple tweak for jailbroken iOS devices running iOS 13, which adds a "Paste and Go" option when you force touch web browsers.

I've managed to make it work with Safari, but the problem comes when I try to use it with other Web browsers. I manage to show the option, but I can't make the web browser to open the link.

I'm posting this here as this is more of a normal programming question than a jailbreaking question because I'm sure there's a way to do this in stock iOS.

Thanks in advance, and sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: @JohnSmith thanks for commenting, but that question is also written by me, haha

Comment: I didn‘t write that, Stackoverflow auto generates it when flagging a question as duplicate